# MVC3 Updating Get Method Parameters. Not working from same View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 and having problems when I call a Get Method.

When I call this code in razor from other View is working well. It sends the keyword, location parameters with the correct present value.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ListSearch", "Job",FormMethod.Get,null))
    {
     <div id="searchBoxes">
  <div id="keywordsSearchBox" >
    <input id="keywords_search_small" type="text" tabindex="2" title="@Resources.What" name="keyword">
    <div class="searchExplain_small">@Resources.KeywordSearchDesc</div>      
  </div>
  <div id="locationSearchBox">
    <input id="location_search_small" type="text" tabindex="3" title="@Resources.Where" name="location" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
    <div class="searchExplain_small">@Resources.LocationSearchDesc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="searchButtonBox_small">
   <input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="@Resources.Search" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"/>
  </div>
  </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult ListSearch(string keyword, string location,int page
=1) ....
```

But, when I am calling the same Get Method from the same view, MVC doesn't update the keyword, location parameters. Instead, it's sending the previous keyword, location parameters.

I am using the same razor code in the home and listSearch view.

**Examples URLs**

```
Home Page => Call GET Method ListSearch (keyword=manager, location=Richmond)
http://localhost:4838/Home/Index =>
http://localhost:4838/Job/ListSearch?keyword=manager&location=Richmond

List Search Page => Call GET Method ListSearch (keyword=lawyer, location=Miami)
http://localhost:4838/Job/ListSearch?keyword=manager&location=Richmond =>
http://localhost:4838/Job/ListSearch?keyword=manager&location=Richmond
```

The parameters are not changing

Any idea of how I can solve it?

Comment: Can you show the code that *isn't* working, instead of showing the code that *is* working and just telling us that some other code is failing?  Also, can you do some in-browser debugging for this?  What is the URL being requested by the GET request when it fails?  What is the form's `action` attribute?  What are the form's values?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The question was edited.

Comment: What is the resulting `form` on the `ListSearch` view?  My suspicion is that the form contains a `keyword` input element, but is making a request to a URL which already has a `keyword` URL value.

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what it's happening. How can I update the keyword parameter?

Comment: It depends on where the URL value is coming from.  Is it in the `action` attribute for the `form`?  If so then you may need to explicitly empty the parameters in `Html.BeginForm`, maybe something like: `Html.BeginForm("ListSearch", "Job", null, FormMethod.Get, null)`  I'm not 100% sure that would do it, you may need to tinker a bit.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. It stills sending the old parameters. :( Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it. Perhaps, it's not the best way to do it, but it works.

I reference the new parameters based on the input text fields and get the value attribute.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Resources.Route_ListSearch, Resources.Route_JobOffer, 
        new { keyword = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(Html.TextBox("keyword").ToHtmlString()).Value, location = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(Html.TextBox("location").ToHtmlString()).Value }, 
        FormMethod.Get, null))
```